# Query with date range

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

I have the following query;

```
foreach (Item sourceChild in source.Axes.GetDescendants()
.OrderBy(x => x["date-optional-1"])
.ThenBy(x => x["date-optional-2"])
.Reverse())
{..}
```

date-optional-1 and 2 are, as the name states, optional, and therefore not guaranteed to be filed.
But if they are, no 1 takes precedence over 2.
I need to add, that if no 1 is filed, then I only need the items from today and forward (it is an event date). How would i go about this in a Where()?

Comment: Does this means you want all events that have "Empty" date-optional-1 OR events with 'date-optional-1' filled and >= TODAY ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (Item sourceChild in source.Axes.GetDescendants()
.Where(x => DateUtil.ParseDateTime(x["date-optional-1"], DateTime.MaxValue) >= DateTime.UtcNow.Date)
.OrderBy(x => x["date-optional-1"])
.ThenBy(x => x["date-optional-2"])
.Reverse())
{..}
```

DateUtil.ParseDateTime converts the string value of the 'date-optional-1' field into a DateTime.

Sitecore stores dates in UTC so we compare that DateTime value with DateTime.UtcNow.Date.  This includes only items with a 'date-optional-1' value >= today in the result set.

DateTime.MaxValue is passed as the second parameter to DateUtil.ParseDateTime so that items with no 'date-optional-1' value are included in the result set.